# RecyclerView row item touch listner

Tags: android, multi-select, android-recyclerview

For multiselect in RecyclerView I used the following [Project](https://github.com/writtmeyer/recyclerviewdemo)

Now I'm facing 2 issues:

- Even if the RecyclerView is empty and you long press ActionMode ActionBar is behaving like row item is selected.
- Following is the row item [image: Row Item RecyclerView],OnClick of Location icon Map should open. But problem is, If I click on Map Icon it gets the click event of Row as well as Map Icon.

On row click I open different fragment and On Click of Map Icon I open Map Fragment.

Fragment Code:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.root_row_item) {
            int idx = mRecyclerView.getChildPosition(v);
            if (actionMode != null) {
                myToggleSelection(idx);
                return;
            } else {
                int pos = idx;
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OtherActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(ContactDetailFragment.KEY_CONTACT_DP, getUserDpFromDB(mCallLogBeanList.get(pos).getNumber()));
                intent.putExtra(ContactDetailFragment.KEY_CONTACT_NAME, mCallLogBeanList.get(pos).getName());
                intent.putExtra(ContactDetailFragment.KEY_CONTACT_NUMBER, mCallLogBeanList.get(pos).getNumber());
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        }
    }
    private void myToggleSelection(int idx) {
    mContactsAdapter.toggleSelection(idx);
    String title = getString(R.string.selected_count, mContactsAdapter.getSelectedItemCount());
    actionMode.setTitle(title);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_delete, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_delete:
            List<Integer> selectedItemPositions = mContactsAdapter.getSelectedItems();
            int currPos;
            for (int i = selectedItemPositions.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                currPos = selectedItemPositions.get(i);
                //                    RecyclerViewDemoApp.removeItemFromList(currPos);
                deleteCallLogsFromDB(currPos);

            }
            mode.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
    this.actionMode = null;
    mContactsAdapter.clearSelections();
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

//==============================================================================================
private class RecyclerViewGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        try {
            View view = mRecyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            onClick(view);
        } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
            Log.e("NullPointerException", ne.getMessage());
        }

        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    }

    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        View view = mRecyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (actionMode != null) {
            return;
        }

        AppCompatActivity aca = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        actionMode = aca.startSupportActionMode(TabCallLogFragment.this);
        int idx = mRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
        myToggleSelection(idx);
        super.onLongPress(e);
    }
}
```

Adapter Part:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListItemViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        holder.Location.setTag(position);
        holder.Location.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: For #2: because you fire the row click in `onSingleTapConfirmed()`. Why you don't use `onClickListener` instead?

Comment: Let me try and check what happens